# How to differentiate between multiple spans on mouseover?

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome-extension, gmail

I'm making a chrome extension where I need to get the email-id when I mouseover to any name i.e. of sender and receivers.

I'm getting the email-id of the sender by mouseover using the div class name:`var exp = $(".acZ").find(".gD")`, where '**gD**' is the div class which contains emai-id.

The same is to be done for receivers, but the div of receivers has multiple span tags, each span tag for a receiver. So the issue is that I'm not able to separate the ids when I mouseover as they are all under the same div class: `var exp1 = $(".xD").find(".g2")`. Every receiver is under '**g2**' class with span tags.

So how can I differentiate between the span tags?

Comment: HOW are you adding the event?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In mouseover event, you can use event.target to get the reference to the DOM element on which the event is triggered.

```
<div class="xD">
   <span class="g2" id="r1">Test1</span>
   <span class="g2" id="r2">Test2</span>
   <span class="g2" id="r3">Test3</span>
   <span class="g2" id="r4">Test4</span>
</div>

<script language="javascript">
   $(".xD").find(".g2").mouseover(function(event)
   {
     console.log("Concerned id " + $(event.target).attr("id"));
   })
</script>
```

Please enable the Developer Console and see the output to verify.

Hope i was able to clarify your requirement...

Comment: Thank you, works now. In gmail they dont have 'id' for the span class. The attribute used is 'email'. So I replaced the 'id' attribute with 'email' and it worked.

Comment: not enough reputation, but I accepted it as correct